# How to trigger CustomClaimHandler when grant_type=password (WSO2 5.10)

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We have external claims, we are getting those with CustomClaimHandler

```
[authentication.framework.extensions]
claim_handler="org.wso2.custom.claim.handler.CustomClaimHandler"
```

it works fine when the grand type is grant_type=authorization_code
But when we run with grant_type=password CustomClaimHandler is not triggered.
Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned behavior is the expected. The Claim Handlers are executed during the authentication process which is going through the Authentication Framework component of the IS. The `authorization_code` grant follows the above approach, whereas the `password` grant follows a different approach to authenticate the users; it authenticates against configured user-stores.

As the flows are different, what you have observed is the expected behavior in the WSO2 IS platform.